# Selenium click button CSS_SELECTOR. Button type = submit

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

Hello Im trying to do a web scrape exercise in Python.
I wanna click a button but is has this html code:

```
button type="submit" name="btnActive" onclick="form.submit();" id="btnActive">  Sign In < /button
```

I am using this code to write other stuff like username:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                      'input#userid')))\
    .send_keys('andres.gonzalez')
```

For the button I tried to use this but it **didn´t worked**:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)\
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                      'button.btnActive')))\
    .click()
```

I´m new to all this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to locate an element By id a `#` should be used and for class a `.` should be used.

So for your problem you need to use

```
button#btnActive
```

instead of

```
button.btnActive
```